# Serve static always add req.url

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using serve-static in ExpressJs in nodeJS,
but I have a problem.
I know it's a function and not a bug, but I don't want to add req.url to my root directory.
When I write:

> var serve = serveStatic('rootDirectory', {index: 'index.html'})

and when I request, for example, 'http://localhost/test'
It serves rootDirectory/test, instead of 'rootDirectory/'.

How can I prevent from that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've searched for many things, and I think the absolute solution is to make it by myself with 'fs'. Thanks anyway

Comment: Instead of adding "closed" to the question's title, you should accept your answer. That way it's easier for others to see that the issue is solved.